# Creating multiple attributes for an element

Tags: php, xml, dom

I figured out how to create a DOM object for XML with the following code (part of it):

```
$xml_item = $xml->createElement('item');
$xml_location = $xml->createElement('location');

$xml_item->setAttribute('item-id', 'abcd');
$xml_item->appendChild($xml_location);
$xml_location->setAttribute('location-id', '1234');
$xml_location->appendChild($xml_quantity);
$xml_quantity = $xml->createElement('quantity', '0');
```

Gives:

```
<item item-id="abcd">       
    <location location-id="1234">
        <quantity>0</quantity>             
    </location>
</item>
```

I want to keep adding more item elements of different attributes to obtain something like this:

```
<item item-id="abcd">       
    <location location-id="1234">
        <quantity>99</quantity>             
    </location>
</item>
<item item-id="qwer">       
    <location location-id="1234">
        <quantity>55</quantity>             
    </location>
</item>
```

But I'm having a hard time figuring this out. How do I use the same variable $xml_item to create multiple entries of "item" element with different attribute as above (i.e. abcd and qwer)? It seems to just over write the first one when I do another $xml_item->setAttribute('item-id', 'qwer') after creating "abcd."

Am I supposed to create multiple copies of "$xml_item" with different variable names (e.g. $xml_item1, _item2, etc. but this seems unreasonably tedious) or can I somehow reuse the same variable ($xml_item) to create multiple entries? The idea is to create as many of those "item" element as I need with different attributes.

Comment: Do you guys happen to know how to convert this object $xml into a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the php.net page for [createElement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php),

> This node will not show up in the
>   document unless it is inserted with
>   (e.g.) DOMNode->appendChild().

So just make sure to keep appending `$xml_item` to your DomDocument object between `createElement()` calls.
ie) `$xml->appendChild($xml_item);`

Comment: Thank you! I wondering what that actually meant.. So I call createElement() followed by appendChild() every time. Superb! It is working.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are missing is that `$xml-item` is a reference to an object - every call you make to one of its function is being called on the same instance of the object, so `setAttribute` will override whatever value you set before.

To create a new instance of the object you need to call

```
$xml_item = $xml->createElement('item');
```

again - **once for every item** that you want to add.

You can use the same variable name - that way `$xml-item` will be referencing a different new instance of 'item' element, and the old instance will no longer be accessible (except from the parent `$xml`).

As brian_d mentioned, after each call to `createElement` you will need to call

```
$xml->appendChild($xml_item);
```

so all of the items will appear in the parent DOM document.

Answer (score 0):

```
$img = $doc->createElement( "img" );

  $imgattr = $doc->createAttribute( "src" );

  $imgattr1 = $doc->createAttribute( "width" );

  $imgattr1->value = 300;

  $imgattr->value = $image['path'];// this the source of my image

  $img->appendChild( $imgattr );

  $img->appendChild( $imgattr1 );

  $b->appendChild( $img );
```

Here img is the element and i have added src and width attribute
and then add value of the attribute and append them to element
If any queries tell me i will share my complete